# How to define mongoose schema for nested documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I need to define the mongoose schema for for nested documents which is given below.

Documents:

```
"Options":[{"Value":["28","30","32","34","36","38","40","42","44","46"],"_id":{"$oid":"5de8427af55716115dd43c8f"},"Name":"Size"},{"Value":["White"],"_id":{"$oid":"5de8427af55716115dd43c8e"},"Name":"Colour"}]
```

I was declaring like below but its not working.

```
const Product = new Schema(
  {
    Options: [{ value: { _id: ObjectId, Name: String } }]
  },
  {
    timestamps: {
      createdAt: "createdAt",
      updatedAt: "updatedAt"
    },
    collection: "products"
  }
);
```

Here I need the schema where if i will directly add/update the same document then it will be added.

Comment: you should make it like this i guess: `{ "Options":[{ "Value":Array, "Name": String }] }`
not sure if you really need `_id` inside those array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your schema like this :

```
{
    Options: [ new Schema ({ value: [...], _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId, Name: String })]
}
```

This is the way to create an array of **subdocuments** with Mongoose. If you don't use the "new Schema" key words, you are actually creating a field with type "Mixed", which needs a different way to handle updates.

You can also omit the _id, it should be added automatically.

You can find more information on subdocument on this page : 
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

...and on mixed type fields : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed

...which will explain shortly the problem.

Comment: With which version ? Yours or the one I proposed ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
{
    Options: [ new Schema ({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),value: [String], Name: String } })]
}
```

Comment: Please do not post link/code only answers. Try explaining why/how your solution would work for the OP. This will help future visitors.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer on Stack Overflow!  Generally Stack Overflow prefers answers that contain more than just code.  Please consider adding an explanation of how this code helps answer the question.